# Does Laravel 4's whereIn() stop fetching rows after finding first values?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Currently I only have 2 users as I'm testing; My `User` model doesn't allow calling the `first()` method on queries with `whereIn()`.

I'm wondering if the `whereIn()` method call on a big user table using an array variable of ids of users will continue comparing a value after already finding it?

My code :

```
$users = User::whereIn('id',$table_of_ids)->remember(2)->get();
```

I get an error thrown when I use the `first()` method like so:

```
$users = User::whereIn('id',$table_of_ids)->remember(2)->first();
```

I'm not sure what it does under the hood, my second question is: is there a method equivalent to combining `whereIn()` and `remember()` and `first()` in one way or another?

### update

my User model :

`protected $table = 'users';

```
protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

protected $fillable = array(

    'field1','field2',...);

public static $rules = array(

    'field1'=>'required|email|max:254|unique:users',        
    'field2'=>'required|alpha_num|max:35|unique:users',
    ...

    );
```

I do not have any relationships in my project, i do all queries manually, and he's my error screenshot :

[image]

The query fetch only id's i'm wondering what sql query does eloquent generate at first to see if the get() method on whereIn is optimized..

Comment: Is $allusers an array of user id's ??

Comment: You have a typo in the second line of code, users should be $users. What kind of error it throws?

Comment: @ArtisanBay yes it is, @ Ján Kyselica corrected thanks

Comment: Just ***what*** is your error thrown? Or do we have to magically conjure up the Exception object from the void?

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::filter()

Comment: Do you use some relationship in User model? Can you post code of this model?

Comment: I am guessing that your User model relationships is creating the issue. Is there a filter() method in your User model ??

Comment: ArtisanBay there is no methods in the User model, only basic properties, i only use filters on Controllers.

Comment: use [ ...->toSql(); ] instead of [ ...->get(); ]  and dd($users); to see the query.

Comment: @ArtisanBay this is what i got : string(42) "select * from `users` where `id` in (?, ?)" i have two users in the table by the way

Comment: I just tried to create a similar one and i was able to fetch values. My code: $user = Profile::whereIn('user_id', array(115, 116))->remember(1)->first(); dd($user);..... Could you also confirm whether the array of id's which you are passing is a single dimensional one, like : $allusers = array(1,2,3,4,5);

Comment: @ArtisanBay you're right sir, i just tried it and got two users and after few dd()'s the problem is located inside my "fetching in collections class" and the filter method can't be applied to $users, the code : function getThisUser($users, $annonce){
  return  $users->filter(function($item) use ($annonce){
   return $item->id == $annonce->user_id;
   })->first();
 }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94337/discussion-between-adam-and-artisanbay).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the obvious solution of using the `take()` method which will add a limit to the query, this way mysql will stop searching after having the nth row that are generally speaking almost close to each other, which is really optimized for queries in big tables.

```
$users = User::whereIn('id',$allusers)->take(count($allusers))->remember(2)->get();
```

I can't use first() because it gives something that is not fetchable with eloquent collection methods for instance "Filter()"